# PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array not showing all results

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am using `sqlsrv_connect` in PHP to connect to an MSSQL database.  The connection works fine and I can perform queries, but I have an issue where the specified returned **row count** is different to the number of iterations performed by the `sqlsrv_fetch_array` **while loop**.  Can anyone help explain why?

Here is my code...

```
// Establish a connection to the MSSQL database
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    // If there was an error format and display
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

// Set the query to the MSSQL database
$tsql = "SELECT xyz FROM db_table WHERE field = ? ORDER BY field ASC";      ***** DUMMY EXAMPLE ******

$params = array($some_value);
    
// Executes the query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params, array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    
// Was there an error
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
echo "Total rows: ".$row_count."<br/>";      ****** THIS RETURNS 28463 ROWS, WHICH IS CORRECT ******

// Update the response
$response = array(0 => array("status" => "success", "value" => "connected", "records" => "0"));

// Set the row count start position
$i = 1;

// Iterate through the results
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // Increase the processed row count
    $i++;
}

echo $i;      ****** THIS RETURNS 5978 ROWS, WHICH IS INCORRECT ******
```

Eventually in production this will be performing an action inside the while loop, but I first need to figure out why it's not iterating through all the rows.

Comment: Try using `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH` instead of `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`.
You can read more about it [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Comment: @EdvinasPlatovas why would that change _anything_ about the number of result records that get fetched in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe `sqlsrv_num_rows` counts the rows. `sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` will consolidate a result set with multiple columns of the same name?

Comment: Did you try to execute `formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors())` at the end of the script to check for possibl errors? `sqlsrv_fetch_assoc()` returns an array on success, `null` if there are no more rows to return, and `false` if an error occurs.

Comment: As a second option, try to change `ClientBufferMaxKBSize` option with `sqlsrv_configure()`, because you are using a client-side cursor. The default value is 10240 KB, so you can easily reach that limit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have increased the ClientBufferMaxKBSize, switched to SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH and unfortunately there is no change.  I executed formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()) at the end of the script and no errors were reported.

Comment: I managed to get this working, I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make this work but using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop, plus explicitly define the row using `SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE`

```
for ($i=0; $i < sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt); $i++){
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $i);

    // Do something here with $row data

    echo "Row: ".trim($i);
}
```

This returns all 28463 rows as expected.